# VBA runtime error '9' when declaring object variable to hold worksheet reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to store a worksheet reference as part of a dynamic range. I keep getting runtime error '9' subscript out of range. Code is as follows:

```
Sub Total_CountT()

'declare object variable to hold reference to worksheet containing cell range
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
 
'declare variables to hold row and column numbers that define named cell range (dynamic)
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
 
 'declare object variable to hold reference to cell range
    Dim myNamedRangeDynamic As Range
 
'declare variable to hold defined name
    Dim myRangeName As String
 
'identify worksheet containing cell range
    Set myWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Full List")
    
 
'identify first row and first column of cell range
    myFirstRow = 4
    myFirstColumn = 1
 
'specify defined name
    myRangeName = "namedRangeDynamic"
 
    With myWorksheet.Cells
 
'find last row and last column of source data cell range
        myLastRow = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        myLastColumn = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
 
'specify cell range
        Set myNamedRangeDynamic = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myFirstColumn))
 
End With
 
'create named range with workbook scope. Defined name is as specified. Cell range is as identified, with the last row and column being dynamically determined
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="FullGuy", RefersTo:=myNamedRangeDynamic
 
Range("Chart!D5").Formula2 = "=COUNTA(FullGuy)"

End Sub
```

The error occurs with the line

```
Set myWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Full List")
```

I am trying to place COUNTA functions referencing the range / subsets of the range stored as FULLGUY from the worksheet FULL LIST. It returns a value of 1, as if the range FULL GUY is nearly empty.

Mousing over the problem code returns "ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Full List") =

In the immediate window I looked up the name of the active worksheet and it returns Full List.

It worked the other day, so Im super stuck, all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check for trailing spaces.

Comment: I havent been able to find any

Comment: That error can only mean that `ThisWorkbook` does not contain a sheet with that name... so something about the name is off.

Comment: Activate the sheet in question and in the Immediate Window put `? ActiveSheet.Name = "Full List"` and hit Enter.

Comment: `?ActiveSheet.Name="Full List"` returns TRUE, `?ActiveSheet.Name` returns Full List

Comment: Then either `ActiveSheet` is not in `ThisWorkbook`, or the error is gone.

Comment: `?ThisWorkbook.Name` returns FUNCRES.XLAM so its referencing some workbook named "FUNCRES.XLAM" not sure where that came from or what it means

Comment: Your module is in the wrong workbook.... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-funcresxlam-ribbonxcodecode-when-i-do-alt/09c8f02f-350d-4c26-a1ba-36a75fee8428. You put it in an add-in associated with the Analysis ToolPak.

Comment: I had to download the toolpak for an op research class.. sheesh. had no idea, what a pita.

Comment: As an aside, the other ‘clue’ is that the ‘w’ in worksheets is lower case: if it were a valid call for an Excel object the VBA editor would have capitalised it to Worksheets. Indicates that either ThisWorkbook doesn’t return a valid object or that it doesn’t have a Worksheets property.